# How to create a Surface plot in Plot.jl from ```solve()``` data

Tags: plot, julia

**MWE:**

```
N₁=5
γ=-1 #nonlinear term strength parameter

g₁(u,p,t) = 1*im*(p[1]*Tridiagonal(fill(1,N₁), fill(-2,N₁+1), fill(1,N₁))*u + γ*u.^3)
vals=0.3*ones(N₁+1)
u0  =map(Complex,vals)


tspan = (0.0,1.0)
prob = ODEProblem(g₁,u0,tspan, [0.6, 1])
sol = solve(prob, Tsit5(), reltol=1e-8, abstol=1e-8)
```

I want to create a surface plot of the absolute value squared data in `sol` similar to what is show here:
[image]

**Attempt:** I want to use the `Plots.jl` package and utilize the `surface()` function. The time data in `sol`  can be accessed as `sol.t` and the spatial data can be accessed as `sol.u`. For example, at `sol.t[2]` the corresponding spatial data is a 6-component vector `sol.u[2]` given by `6-element Vector{ComplexF64}: 0.2999679677368571 - 0.0030866750511122525im 0.30001119699789686 - 0.000402829297042341im 0.2999991898889756 - 0.00040261260929592426im 0.2999991898889756 - 0.00040261260929592426im 0.30001119699789686 - 0.000402829297042341im 0.2999679677368571 - 0.0030866750511122525im`

The components of the vector are the spatial data at the first, second, third, fourth, fifth, and sixth grid points of the discretized space. I know via broadcasting I can obtain the absolute valued squared data by `abs.sol`

I tried `surface(range(-5,5), sol.t, abs.(sol))`, but this resulted in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the solution object,

```
x, y = range(1, 6), sol.t
zvals = abs.(sol)
squeeze(z) = vec(z)[1]
surface(x, y, (x, y)-> squeeze(zvals[x, indexin(y, sol.t)]))
```

the above code works to create a surface plot, but I am not sure that is what you want.

[image]

In the call to `surface` the first and second arguments are the grid points and the third argument is a function that gives the height at said grid point.

Comment: Could you please explain the squeeze syntax and ```(x, y)-> squeeze(zvals[x, indexin(y, sol.t)])``` ? I do not know what these do and cannot find squeeze in the documentation. Further, the output is not what I expect which is why I ask.

Comment: @KZ-Spectra I defined `squeeze` to remove an unnecessary singleton dimension. The third argument wants function taking `(x, y)` to return a scalar value for height but `zvals[x, indexin(y, sol.t)]` is vector or array like `[v]` or something (I forgot what exactly).